# How to resolve the grant type error in linked in

Tags: linkedin-api

Can any one help in resolving a error while trying to get a acess code in linkedin from a user ?

The url i am passing is

```
https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken?grant_type=authorization_code
                                           &code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE
                                           &redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI
                                           &client_id=YOUR_API_KEY
                                           &client_secret=YOUR_SECRET_KEY
```

I got the authorization code

And the error i am getting after passing this URL is

{"error_description":"missing required parameters, includes an invalid parameter value, parameter more than once. : invalid grant_type","error":"invalid_request"}

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that you properly URL encode the values in the query parameters and that you pass the exact value (well, URL encoded of course) for the `redirect_uri` that you used in the initial authorization request to the `https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization` endpoint.